# How to get range of data plotted by bokeh from figure object?

Tags: python, bokeh

I am using Bokeh library for plotting some scatter plot.
Is it possible and how to get range of coordinates of points (plotted to plot) in actual data units from figure object?

```
fig = figure()
fig.line(x_coords, y_coords)

assert fig.x_range is None  # this is sic!
```

Another interesting question is getting same range of coordinates of points in pixels.

Comment: Hi, could you add some code? Do you want to get the pixel values or the actual data points? What do you actually mean by getting range of points?

Comment: Range of points coordinates. In actual data will be enough.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the (default) auto-ranging `DataRange1d`, the values you are seeking are not available in Python, they are only computed in the browser, in JavaScript.

Otherwise, you can exert explicit control over ranges:

```
fig = figure(x_range=(0, 10))
```